# How to add HUnit to a Yesod project

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod, hunit

I'm quite a beginner to Yesod and not experienced with Cablal - I used the scaffolding tool to initialise a new Yesod project, wrote some handlers and other code and now I'm struggling with adding some HUnit tests - how to do this in a best way? Using cabal's test-suite option? If yes then how exactly? Some examples of the .cabal file and how to run the tests would be helpful.

Comment: I don't have nearly enough experience to answer this question properly, but you may find the [Cabal user guide](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/#test-suites) and the [Hunit user giude](http://hunit.sourceforge.net/HUnit-1.0/Guide.html) useful.

Comment: Been there already, the problem is that the default (sraffolded) Yesod setup is a little different then ordinary cabal project - there is no Setup.hs file and I run the project using "yesod --dev devel" tool which uses cabal-dev. Actually I don't know how to run my tests - they of course have a lot of dependencies with my handler and yesod modules

Answer (score 0):

yes, you should use the cabal test suite. There is a pull request on github to add testing to the default Yesod scaffold. It will be merged soon.